# Evaluation of a summation involving the use of Mehler's formula

Tags: summation, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

I came across an infinite summation of the following form involving the product of two Hermite polynomials while solving a physics problem.

> $f(x,y;u,a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a+bn)H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$

where, $a$, $b$, and $u$ are constants.

I figured that one part of this sum i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$
can be evaluated using the [Mehler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel) but I'm wondering how to compute the other part which involves a factor of $n$ inside the sum i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b n H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$.

I tried partially differentiating the Mehler's fromula with respect to either $x$ (or $y$). However, I'm left with the sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n H_{n-1}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$ which is not quite what I want to compute the other part in my summation.

I'm looking to get a closed-form expression for the full summation if it converges. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n=u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a+bn) H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n=\big(a+b\,u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\big)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you! That was pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Svyatoslav It turns out that in my sum, $x$ and $y$ are actually functions of $u$ and not independent variables. Therefore, I'm curious how this would work if I have the following sum instead: $g(x,y;u,a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a+bn)H_{n}(x(u))H_{n}(y(u))}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$

Comment: You should separate $u$ from $x, y$. So, evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$ first (get a closed form depending on $x,y,u$), then differentiate it with respect to $u$, and only after use the fact that $x, y$ are the functions of $u$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I also have terms of sums of the following forms in my expression: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 H_{n-1}(x(u))H_{n-1}(y(u))}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1) H_{n-2}(x(u))H_{n}(y(u))}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n H_{n-1}(x(u))H_{n}(y(u))}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$.

Comment: Further, I'm dealing with the special case when $x(u)=y(u)$ in these sums. Therefore, I evaluated them by noting: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 H_{n-1}(x)^2}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n\big\rvert_{y=x}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1) H_{n-2}(x)H_{n}(x)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n\big\rvert_{y=x}$

Comment: and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n H_{n-1}(x)H_{n}(x)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n\big\rvert_{y=x}$. I used the closed-form expression for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^n$ to evaluate the partial derivatives at $y=x$ and then finally substituted the function: $x(u)$ in the resulting expression. Please correct me if I'm wrong.